# jQuery not working with IE 11

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

`Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'`

```
'jQuery' is undefined
```

I'm using IE 11,

/jquery-2.1.1.min.js

jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js

and jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.js (theme roller)

Before 2.1.1, i was using 1.11.1 with chrome (worked fine)

I have tried [this](http://www.markadrake.com/blog/2013/12/13/sharepoint-workflows-fail-using-ie11/) fix but it did not work for me

Comment: IE11 does support `addEventListener()`. You're running in a compatibility mode of some sort. Check your options and your console.

Comment: my page was an intranet site, & IE had compatibility mode set to default for this. thank you for your solution. this has fixed the issue

Comment: The solution that @FrédéricHamidi proposed solved this issue for me as well.  Either one of you should add that as the answer below and mark it as so for future readers.  :)

Comment: To disable the compatibility mode, add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in your html header.

Comment: In my case, it started working when I went back to an older version of jquery. with jquery 2.2.3 it would show '$ is not defined' even when I wasn't running in compatibility mode. I switched it to 1.11.3 and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem was caused because the page was an intranet site, & IE had compatibility mode set to default for this. **IE11** does support `addEventListener()`

Answer (score 115):

As Arnaud suggested in a comment to the original post, you should put this in your html header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

I don't want any cred for this. I just want to make it more visible for anyone else that come here.

Comment: So, I'm assuming if your site is developed in MVC format with a lot of partial views, this would then go in the Shared/_Layout page?

Comment: @Brian. Then I will assume you are using asp.net and therefor I ain't got a clue. But I did a quick search and there seems to be a lot of answers on where to put meta tags.

Comment: My paged loaded and ran correctly in Google Chrome, but refused to run javascript in Internet Explorer. This solution fixed my problem too.

Comment: You're getting creds anyway! :) Thanks.. This solved it for me. Thanks @Arnaud as well.

Comment: If you didn´t want any cred for this, you would make it wiki ;)
And a comment under the chosen answer is pretty visible location.

Answer (score 8):

For me the issue turned out to be I was using es6's right arrow functions `=>` as opposed to `function ()`.

Replacing `=>` with `function ()` resolved for me.

I had assumed it was a jQuery issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Arnaud & @Conny for highlighting this answer. This really helped me.
I would like to add one more thing here is, adding this line `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">` just after the title in  tag prior to all meta tags is must for to work as it overrides the compatibility mode of IE.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the "x_ua_compatible" tag to the page didn't work for me. Instead I added it as an HTTP Respone Header via IIS and that worked fine.

In IIS Manager select the site then open HTTP Response Headers and click Add:

[image]

The site didn't need restarting, but I did need to Ctrl+F5 to force the page to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Place this meta tag after head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: It should be `content="IE=edge"`

Comment: Why are you copying an old answer?