# Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent' InternetExplorer 11

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, internet-explorer-11

If I press the form send button "Saada" in *IE11*, I will get an error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent'
```

I have found that this is an *IE11* problem, but the only solution I have found is to use my developer tools and set the browser to run in *IE9* mode for example.

But I want everyone to use my website without using their developer tools.
Do you know some other solution I could try. Or maybe I have to import some other *Jquery* libraries?

Other browsers work fine, but this only happens in IE11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

attachEvent is a deprecated function used in older versions of Internet Explorer.
For modern browsers use this instead.

```
el.addEventListener(evt,func,false);
```

See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

You could also create a function which checks which function to use

```
function addListener(el, event, func){
    if (el.addEventListener) {
       el.addEventListener(event, func, false);
    }
    else {
       el.attachEvent("on"+event, func);
    }
}
```

Then you can attach your event by doing this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
addListener(element, 'click', function(){
    alert('You have clicked!');
});
```

If you are unable to to this then perhaps a polyfill will work instead. Try to insert this somewhere:

```
if(!document.attachEvent){
  Object.prototype.attachEvent=function(event,func){
    this.addEventListener(event.split('on')[1], func);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Okay, Can I simply add this function to the bottom of my page and it repair everything automatically?

Comment: Yes you can add it to the end of your js if you like. I have added an examle of how to use it

Comment: I am using Gravity Forms plugin for Wordpress and I can't find where is the code for submit button click that I have to change.

Comment: Ah ok i didn't realise you were using a plugin. Try the polyfill code i inserted in my answer.

Comment: Should I change something in this code? Right now it gives me one more error: Object doesn't support property or method 'exec'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077612/jquery-not-working-with-ie-11

Found something like this, but I don't know what they did to fix this.

Comment: Problem Solved! I used latest jquery version and now it works with IE. But I hope everything else still works :)

Answer (score 13):

The javascript method attachEvent was replaced with the method addEventListener in IE11.

JQuery 1.10.1 still uses this method in case of IE > 8. This will cause javascript compilation errors.

**JQuery 1.10.2 seems to have solved this problem.**

Hope this will help

Comment: What an obscure version problem, thanks to you we saved a ton of headaches.