# Getting Error "Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent'" in IE11 but work in IE8, IE9, IE10

Tags: java, internet-explorer-11, servlet-filters

I am working on Java `doFilter` Popup and open iFrame jQuery popup with URL which called SAP.

My code is working for Chrome, Mozilla firefox, IE8, IE9 and IE10 but I am getting a:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent'" Error in
> IE11.

Is there any issue with IE11 ?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659450/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-attachevent-internetexplorer-11

Comment: @EvanKnowles i checked it and but they give update jquery for solved it problem at end of their conversation but i am using updated jquery already.

Comment: We're going to need to see more code then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older versions of IE, `attachEvent` is used to attach an event handler for some event on some element. But as per the update [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx), starting with IE11, `attachEvent` is deprecated and you should use `addEventListener` instead.

IE has included support for `addEventListener` from IE9 and above only. So if you still need to support IE8, I suggest you use some cross-browser library like jQuery to bind event handlers instead of vanilla javascript.

As you're already using jQuery, you can bind events like below

```
$('#yourElement').on('click', function(){
   // do something when you click on yourElement
});
```

Comment: with use of jQuery click event i solved my problem. you save my lot of time. thanks

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

A hack. You may check for IE11 before doing this. I am targeting IE11 only so not doing any checks.

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        Element.prototype.attachEvent = function(ename, e) {
            this.addEventListener(ename, e);
        }

        Element.prototype.detachEvent = function(ename, e) {
            this.removeEventListener(ename, e);
        }
</script>
```