# Javascript not working when located in external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, safari9

my Javascript (jQuery) is working fine in newer browsers (Chrome, Firefox, safari 10+) but not in slightly older Browers (Safari 9, IE 11..).

It however does work fine, when I include it directly on the page and dont try to load it from an external file. I have been at it for hours and I cant figure out what the problem is..

My Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function($) {


  $(".monatsInput").on("click", function () {
    console.log("clicked");

    $(".monatsWahl").css("border-color", "lightgrey")
    $(this).parent().css("border-color", "#4CA3D8");

    var newPrice = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".angebotsPreis").html(newPrice);
  })


// Mobile Nav
// --------------------------------------------------
// --------------------------------------------------

$("#burgerNav").on("click", function () {
  $(".navList").toggle("display");
});


// Back to previous page
  function goBack() {
      window.history.back();
  }


$(document).foundation();
})
```

Im not sure which part of the HTML to include, so the entire page can be viewed here:

[www.immobilienheld24.de](http://www.immobilienheld24.de)

I hope someone has an idea.

Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you have so little Javascript on the page, you would be better off having it within the HTML as inline element.

Comment: even if it has to be included on every page? Which the Mobile-nav part what be

Comment: If you have to include it in every page, then **better** to have it as an external file.

Comment: can you expand upon the `but not in older browsers` issue? what does the console output?

Comment: Have you read this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077612/jquery-not-working-with-ie-11

Comment: I will try that, but its not just an IE problem. Safari 9 isnt working either.

Comment: You can add console.log in js to make sure that this code runs. My guess is that you get error BEFORE this code in js.

Comment: Ive tried that :/ As said before - the code works finde, when its inline. And it works fine in some browsers.

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid character: '`' in  app.js:10208. Replace this chars with single or double brackets (' or ")

Comment: thats not part of my JS - so Im assuming its part of the jQuery library.. maybe.. if commented out the Foundation JS, so I dont know what else it would be